# Serializable Transactions vs SELECT FOR UPDATE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, isolation-level, acid

I have a stock table with columns: `id, available, sold, status` fields. Before increasing `sold` field I have to check if `sold` + `x` is less and equal than `available`. To make sure every transaction uses the freshest data and not allow other transactions to modify it I used `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

`START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM stock WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE;`

*--some backend logic here check if sold + x <= available is true update else unlock --*

`UPDATE stock set sold = sold + x where id = 1;
COMMIT;`

But I am not really sure if I am doing it right. I looked into MySQL documentation and old questions, read about isolation levels. Should I set the transaction isolation level as `serializable` or it is totally redundant?

I am using MySQL 8.0.17.

Answer (score 0):

Add the 'available' check?  And didn't you mean to use the same table?

```
UPDATE stock
    set sold = sold + 4
    where id = 1
    AND sold + x <= available;
```

The `FOR UPDATE` say "This process *may* change this row(s); keep your hands off." and "If any other process is busy mucking with this row(s), I should wait."

If the `WHERE` clause on the `UPDATE` fails, then the update won't be performed.  So put the business logic (eg, test against `available`) there.

The `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` delineate how long this process is being possessive about this row(s).

Comment: Yes, the whole operation happens in one table. Will  `AND sold + x <= available`  be enough if multiple queries try to change the same row? I know updates are atomic but I am not sure how it will work out with concurrent requests.

Comment: @Shahin - The `FOR UPDATE` blocks changes to that row until the transaction finishes.

Comment: I noticed my mistake in question body, fixed. Yes, I just need to increase/decrease one column - sold - with `id = 1`. But this field stores sensitive data, it has to be less and equal than `available` field. I am not sure the update query without `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` will work in that case.   Shouldn't I just lock that row and allow MySQL to perform only one operation at the same time?

Comment: @Shahin - The `FOR UPDATE` provides the lock.  See what I added to my Answer.

Comment: I understand your point, your query will check `sold + x <= available` condition if true then process it. Is it possible that MySQL could update the field in the middle of the process? I mean,  to update something internally MySQL has to pull the data then update it, right? In the middle of this process, another query cannot change that field, right?

Comment: @Shahin - No chance of another connection sneaking in.  That's what the `BEGIN.. FOR UPDATE ..COMMIT` does for you.  Read about ACID (in relation to transactions), where A is for Atomic.

Comment: I mean without `BEGIN FOR...UPDATE` portion, only straightforward update query is dangerous to work with it?

Comment: @Shahin - If you can do everything you need in the `UPDATE` and you have `autocommit=ON`, then it will work.  This is because each statement would effectively a transaction.  (That's what that setting means.)  Again, isolation mode should not matter.

Comment: I got your point. Thank you very much!